# r blogdown: project content disappears

Tags: r, r-markdown, blogdown

I am wondering why my projects section on my blogdown Website does not show any of my projects even if I do have projects in that directory.

[image]

Comment: please add a reprex

Comment: This is happening to me too! And i'm not sure how to create a reprex, when it's a product of multiple code files being magically stitched together in the background by Hugo. What info would even be useful? 

@jenny-the-queen - does it show when you `serve_site()`, but not when it's live? 

My setup:  
Hugo version 0.73.0  
Blogdown: 0.20

Comment: My last resort is to reinstall Hugo. It's not smart but it works.